# Плавная прокрутка к блоку vue js

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь сделать "якорь" на vue js, но ничего не получается
1) Есть класс header, где находится само навигационное меню
2) Далее идут 4 блока (один из них в классе main, остальные в div)
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку из навигационного меню возникала плавная прокрутка к блоку.
Делаю так: ... `<li><button type="button" @click="scrollTo('services')">Услуги</button></li>`  ...
Вызов
... 
    
    
...

Код на vue

```
var anchor = new Vue({
  methods: {
    scrollTo(refName) {
      var element = this.$refs[refName];
      var top = element.offsetTop;
      window.scrollTo(0, top);
    }
  }
})
```

На ссылки кликаю - не работает. Не говоря уже о плавной прокрутке

P.S. дополнительно нужно сделать, чтобы ссылка меняла цвет, когда экран находится на активном блоке

Comment: Вызов: <div v-el="services">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видео демо работы: https://yadi.sk/i/AZNoazQiMxcfpg

Ссылка на js fiddle (простой вариант): https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/5n4urv18/3/

Ссылка на js fiddle (вариант с анимацией): https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/rcwauhm7/5/

Пояснения к коду:

```
async openSimpleSlide(number_slide){
    // Получение ссылки на элемент
    let slide = this.$refs[`slaid-${number_slide}`]
    // Определение расстояния от начала страницы до нужного элемента
    let top = window.scrollY + slide.getBoundingClientRect().y;
    // Перемотка
    window.scrollTo(0, top)
}
```

Вариант более сложный, но с плавной прокруткой

```
async openSlide(number_slide){
    // Получение ссылки на элемент
    let slide = this.$refs[`slaid-${number_slide}`]
    // Число циклов в анимации, ее качество
    let count = 100;
    // Определение раастояние от начала страницы до элемента
    let top = window.scrollY + slide.getBoundingClientRect().y;
    // Определение раастояние от начала страницы до элемента
    let start_top = window.scrollY;
    // Вычисление перемещения (скролла) за одну итерацию
    let delta = (top - window.scrollY) / 100;
    // Начало анимации
    for (let i=0;i<100; i++) {
        // Ожидание 1 секунды, деленного на качетсво анимации
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                resolve()
            }, 1000 / count)
        })
        // Выполнение перемещения на значение delta с учетом текущего скролла
        window.scrollTo(0, start_top + delta)
    }
},
```

Comment: Удачи. Мне сегодня тоже очень сильно помогли))

Comment: Спасибо!! Буду пробовать, вроде разобрался :)

Comment: Только вот такой вопрос. Если у меня все блоки располагаются в разных div - ах, как реализовать это: "el: "#app","

Comment: Это id элемента, который является для них контейнером, т.е. все эти блоки расположены вложены в элемента с id `app`

Comment: Это я понял. Только у меня нет такого контейнера. Они расположены в разных блоках. Как быть а такой ситуации?

Comment: Для них все равно должен быть один общий контейнер, пусть даже это будет тег `body` . Не имеет значения уровень вложенности, важна лишь возможность найти элемент в дереве узлов.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо большое! А еще такой вопрос, если внутри такого контейнера есть еще один, для него же тоже можно добавить представление "new Vue"?

Comment: Просто тогда возникают конфликты с вложенным представлением, и ничего не работает

Comment: Вложение, насколько я знаю,  не работает. Но можно разместить их рядом, главное, измените id контейнера. PS пометьте, что вопрос решеный))

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать) спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 1):

Все просто.

```
window.scrollTo({
    top: 1000,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Comment: var anchor = new Vue({
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 1000,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
})   Получается, так? А в html как тогда? Нам же нужно к конкретному имени блока обратиться, и ссылка идет на конкретное имя

Comment: а это уже зависит от фреймворка) как это записать...

Comment: Пишу на vue.js, все перепробовал. Ничего не получается =(